# Is there an exact correspondence between Seiberg-Witten theory and mirror symmetry?

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, supersymmetry, seiberg-witten-theory, mirror-symmetry

Seiberg-Witten solution gives an algebraic geometrical description of the quantum moduli of 4d $\mathcal{N}=2 $ SUSY gauge theory. However, the solution seems purely constructive and does not enjoy full generality to me. **I'm asking for an intuitive and thorough understanding of Seiberg-Witten theory.**

In the last section of [hep-th/9510023](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9510023), the author mentions a speculation about the "stringy origin" of Seiberg-Witten theory:[image: Similarity between Seiberg-Witten duality and mirror symmetry]

I'm wondering if the correspondence between Seiberg-Witten theory and mirror symmetry shown in the image is exact. In particular, can we find a *loop* in the moduli space of Calabi-Yau manifolds that produces monodromy matrix iff it surronds a singularity?

Let's call attention to the fact that in 2d CFT, the *Verlinde lines* are also loops in the moduli space of punctured Riemann surfaces, having their monodromy matrix. More strikingly, 2d CFT and 4d SUSY gauge theories share the same *modular geoup* $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$. I'm not sure if it can contribute to a thorough understanding of Seiberg-Witten theory.

I also heard that Gaiotto duality generalizes Seiberg-Witten theory and class S theory makes use of Seiberg-Witten curve. But I know little about them and I'm not sure if they are relevant to the stuffs I mentioned above.